# Unable to load external properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, groovy, gradle, spring-boot

I have a very basic spring boot command line app into which I am trying to load properties from an application.yml file that is present inside my project. The project is built using gradle and I am using groovy as the language.

Now wherever I place the application.yml file, I can't seem to be able to assign its values to the configuration properties bean. The files are as below

**application.yml**

```
my:
  name: "some name"
  servers:
    - dev.bar.com
    - foo.bar.com
```

**Config.groovy**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class Config {

    private List<String> servers = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String name

    public List<String> getServers() {
        return this.servers;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

**Worker.groovy** The Command line runner

```
@Component
class Worker implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    Config config

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        println "Running a test app"
        println config.name
        println config.getServers()
    }
}
```

**Directory Structure**

```
app-name
  -build.gradle
  -src
    -main
      -groovy
        -config
          -application.yml
        -com
          -company
            -app
              Worker.groovy
              Config.groovy
              Application.groovy
```

I also tried renaming application.yml to application.properties as well as adding it under the com.company.app project, but the worker class's run method always prints the property as null. I believe I may have missed something very basic, but can't seem to find what it has.

Let me know if I need to provide any additional details.

Comment: That worked! I wish the docs were clearer on this. Why don't you post this as an answer instead of a comment and I will accept it as a valid answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application.yml` should go under `src/main/resources/config`.

Resources are processed (copied) from `src/main/resources` directory.

By default the groovy plugin ignores other than groovy classes in `src/main/groovy`.